# Python, Telethon send_file send_message

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using a private channel/group to "backup" some photos/videos. I am using Telethon to send the files. Using the send_file function, I am sending groups of 10 files, but they appear in Telegram with the current datetime, obviously. I would like to have a "timeline" of the photos sent. For example: I have a folder called "2012-06-05" with many photos.
I would like to know if it is possible for me to set a retroactive date for the files sent, thus leaving the message as if it were from June 05, 2012 at 00:00. Is it possible to set a date and time on messages/files sent using the send_file or send_message functions?

Currently I can send photos and videos, but they appear with the current date. I would like to provide a retroactive date so that the message would be as sent in the past.

Comment: “*I'm using a private channel/group to "backup" some photos/videos*” Sounds like what you need is a *proper* “*backup*” system rather than using a Telegram channel in a way in which it was not intended to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set a date and time on messages/files sent using the send_file or send_message functions?

No it's not possible to 'fake' the time/date of a message in Telegram.

---

Glad it isn't; otherwise people could 'insert' a message in the past and lie about it ;)